# user/login page - no access to it

Tags: 7, users

I want to add a Login link in the user menu. When I give it the path 'user/login', I get the message:
The path 'user/login' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.

If I give it a path of 'user', it works.  However, that's not the path I want, because it will still be visible to the logged-in user.

If I give it a full path, http://mysite.com/user/login, it works BUT isn't hidden from the logged-in user.  Puzzling.

Any ideas?  I am pretty sure I could use a module to handle this, but it seems like overkill.

Comment: You cannot see `user/login` path after logged in. In fact there is nothing a logged in user can do.

Comment: Right, but I can't put that path into the User menu.  I get the error above when I enter it as a link.

Comment: If you use proper menu or drupal `l()` function to print the link, it will not be there for logged in users. Means it will follow Drupal permissions.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the [Sub-pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module simply:

1. Disable the subpathauto module.
2. Add your menu item(s) for user/login.
3. Re-enable the subpathauto module.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to everyone who answered.  I was not asking about whether or not the login link was visible, but was instead asking how to enter the user/login path on the user menu or in the URL aliases without getting an error.

I solved it by using the path user/login? instead of user/login.  So simple, so much time wasted.

Comment: wow, too clever. It worked and can't be anymore simple.

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping it in a conditions like these?

```
if (user_is_logged_in()) {
  // Do something.
}
```

or

```
if (user_is_anonymous()) {
  // Do something.
}
```

A useful link - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_menu_site_status_alter/7

Comment: Thanks for the hint, so I no longer user !user_is_logged_in() anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

That error message is show from the [form validation handler](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.admin.inc/function/menu_edit_item_validate/7) used by the form that allows you to add a menu item, or edit it; it calls [drupal_valid_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_valid_path/7), which contains the following code.

```
return $item && $item['access'];
```

As [@Nikhil M](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/4471/nikhil-m) said in [his comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75824/user-login-page-no-access-to-it#comment83930_75824), logged-in users don't have access to that menu item, which means `$item['access']` is `FALSE`.

The only way I found to add that link was first creating a path alias (e.g. user-login) to /user/login, and then using the path alias when creating the menu item.

[image: screenshot]

Apparently it works.

[image: screenshot]

Once logged in, the menu item doesn't appear.

[image: screenshot]

I have also tried with a different menu (e.g. the Main menu) and it works.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

At first, it seemed not to work, since the link was not shown when I logged out. To see the login link, I had to clean the Drupal cache, and refresh the page from Firefox after logging out.

Comment: This is a great-looking solution, and I was hopeful, but the URL alias is giving me the same error message when I enter /user/login, so I can't make the alias either.

Comment: I am not having a problem with whether it shows up if you are logged in or not.  I know it will work if I can just get either the menu or the URL alias config to accept user/login.

Comment: I didn't have any problem for the path alias to accept user/login as existing system path of the alias. If that makes any difference, I used the user 1 account to set the path alias.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues came up with a simple solution that I'm sharing in case it helps others. "Basically, you can't edit an existing menu item that links to user/login, you have to create a whole new one. I did that and it's working now!"

So you can create a menu item with the path in question (user/login), but you'll never be able to edit it. If you want to change the text down the road,create a new menu item and delete the old.